# Why does VarType() ALWAYS return 8204 for Arrays

Tags: arrays, vbscript

In the [`VarType` MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/3kfz157h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) Microsoft documentation for VBScript's `VarType` function it says (With bold emphasis):

> "Remarks The VarType function never returns the value for Array by
>   itself. It is always added to some other value to indicate an array of
>   a particular type. The value for Variant is only returned when it has
>   been added to the value for Array to indicate that the argument to the
>   VarType function is an array. **For example, the value returned for an
>   array of integers is calculated as 2 + 8192, or 8194**. If an object has
>   a default property, VarType (object) returns the type of its default
>   property."

BUT

Code such as

```vb
Dim A,I1, I2, I3
I1 = 1
I2 = 2
I3 = 3
A = Array(I1,I2,I3)

Dim A2
A2 = Split("Test,Test,Test",",")

AT = VarType(A)
AT2 = VarType(A2)
IT1 = VarType(I1)
IT2 = VarType(I2)
IT3 = VarType(I3)

WScript.Echo IT1
WScript.Echo IT2
WScript.Echo IT3
WScript.Echo AT & " - 8192 = " & AT - 8192
WScript.Echo AT2 & " - 8192 = " & AT2 - 8192
WScript.Echo CStr(VarType(A(2)))
```

returns

```
2 
2
2
8204 - 8192 = 12 
8204 - 8192 = 12
2
```

`I1` - `I3` ALL return their proper `vbInteger` AND, when referenced individually in their array, ALSO return `vbInteger`, but the array insists it's an array of `vbVariant`.

Unless I'm COMPLETELY missing something here it seems that in SPITE of the documentation there is no way to create an array where the items are ALL of the SAME type and have `VarType` recognize it as as anything but an array of `vbVariant`.

I feel like this should already be a question but i came up empty searching through here so feel free to link if I missed the existing questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

> In VBScript, variables are always of one fundamental data type,
>   Variant.

Data contained in the variable can be of any type, but variables itself are always of `Variant` type. Checking with `VarType` the contents of a position of an array will return the type of data contained. But the array itself is a compound of  "cells" of `Variant` type

So, in your case `VarType` will return `vbArray` (8192) + `vbVariant` (12) = `8204`

Comment: The documentation should say: "_Arrays_ are always of type `vbVariant + vbArray`". Non-array variables and array elements can be any Variant subtype.

Comment: @Bond, No, the documentation is right. `VarType` return the type for the array. You can not create a integer array in VBScript itself, but a query to a property or a method call to a COM component can return it and `VarType` will properly identify the data type.

Comment: Right. I think we're on the same page. _VBScript itself_ can only create `vbArray + vbVariant` arrays (Array() function, Dim, arrays returned from VBScript functions, etc), no matter if the elements are homogenous. I'm not saying you can't end up with a non-vbVariant array from other means. The `ADO Stream` object, for example can return `vbArray + vbByte (UI1)` arrays.

Comment: I just think the documentation quote in your answer is confusing because it doesn't explain why VBScript can't create arrays of any other type but `vbVariant`. Sure everything is a Variant (as your quote says) and you can query its subtype with `VarType` but your quote doesn't explain why _arrays_ can't be created for specific Variant subtypes.

Comment: So in other words VBScript is smart enough to get the proper type from a COM object but NOT smart enough to do the same thing with its own code. 

It seems like they might have want to, I don't know mention that this little 8192 + Type ONLY applies to COM objects and arrays they return.  

Luckily for me all my arrays are going to be VBScript created so my validation needs just got simpler

Comment: @TofuBug It's not about "getting the proper type". It's about _creating the proper type_. VBScript, intrinsically, cannot _create_ anything other than `vbArray + vbVariant`, even if your array contains only `vbInteger` or some other Variant subtype.

Comment: @Bond, to create an integer (or any other type) array you need to **declare** that the cells in the array are integer. But the VBScript language does not allow you to do it as there is no type declaration, anything is a Variant. But as VBScript is not an island and "usually" talks with COM components, the `VarType` function included the ability to handle different types (and not all) from outside VBScript itself

Comment: @MCND Right. Everything is a Variant. But VBScript _does_ understand Variant subtypes that aren't `vbVariant`. If I write: `i = 4`, VBScript accurately creates a Variant of subtype `vbInteger`. So you don't need a special *declare* statement for VBScript to use the proper Variant subtype. It just doesn't do it for homogenous arrays. `i = 4` (`vbInteger`). `a = Array(4)` (`vbArray + vbVariant`). No integer declaration is used in either, but one is properly identified as `vbInteger`.

Comment: Of course I can see why they did it this way. It's a scripting language after all and it should be easy to use. If I create `a = Array(4)` and VBScript created it as `vbArray + vbInteger` and then I tried to add a string element to the array, I'm now breaking the `vbArray + vbInteger` contract. So it's certainly easier to create it as `vbArray + vbVariant` and let the user put whatever they want in any array. But you do lose some nifty abilities that can only be done with variant-subtype-defined arrays. True binary arrays, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply an error in documentation:

```
==>type D:\VB_scripts\SO\30511987.vbs
option explicit
Dim ii, aA(3)
aA(1)=5
aA(2)="string"
aA(3)=Now

Wscript.Echo "array", VarType(aA), TypeName(aA)

For ii=0 To UBound(aA)
  Wscript.Echo "aA(" & CStr(ii) & ")", VarType(aA(ii)), TypeName(aA(ii))
Next

==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\30511987.vbs
array 8204 Variant()
aA(0) 0 Empty
aA(1) 2 Integer
aA(2) 8 String
aA(3) 7 Date

==>
```

Comment: Fair enough the "obvious" answer never even occurred to me.

Comment: No, there is no error in the documentation. Just suppose you have a property in a COM component with a definition like `Public Property Get Items() as Integer()`. The returned array will be of type integer and `VarType` will report it as `8194`. But arrays created from VBScript will be always Variant

Comment: @MCND there is an error (or a _mistake_ rather), see the `2 + 8192` example in the link you have provided... However, until your answer I never _understood_ the `vbVariant` constant description: `12 Variant (used only with arrays of Variants)`. I did _know_ it but **I understand**  now!!! Thanks..

Comment: @MCND and that's why I gave an example of a _heterogeneous_ array in opposite to _homogeneous_ one alluded in that erroneous `2 + 8192` example

Comment: @JosefZ, I agree. It is at least *ambiguous*. The usage of *`... for an array of integers ...`* leads to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Although VBscript lacks the syntax to declare arrays of any type other than "variant array of variants", its variant type and variant array type are not limited in that way. The variant type is a COM type, AKA a Visual Basic 4+ type, AKA a version of an Excel xloper (an Excel cell type).

You can get VBscript "vartype" to return any other kind of array type by using it on an array created externally:

```
obj = CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")
obj.SetLength 0
obj.WriteByte 1
obj.WriteByte 2

A = obj.ToArray() 
wscript.echo vartype(A)
```